# How can I view XMLHttpRequests in IE 8?

Tags: jquery, ajax, debugging, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest

Firstly, apologies if this is a duplicate. I've searched and looked at *related questions* but haven't found this question.

I'm debugging an AJAX problem in IE8. My throbber seems to spin forever, and on the *on completion* callback for my AJAX (jQuery's `$.getJson()`) it is meant to disappear. Of course, it works fine in Firefox / Safari. However in IE8 my throbber spins forever.

Is there a way in IE8 to see the XMLHttpRequests like in Firebug? Can I view their completion, their response etc?

I have had a look in the Developer Tools, but could not find it. Is FirebugLite the only option, and can it even do this?

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

I've since solved the problem I was having, but I am curious still as to how I can view them in IE8.

Answer (score 4):

I use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

for debugging requests in IE

Answer (score 2):

Two quick search results:

1. [httpwatch](http://www.httpwatch.com)
2. [debugbar](http://www.debugbar.com)

Not open source though and I have not tried them either. First one's reviews look promising.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.charlesproxy.com/ a paid solution for Windows, Mac and Linux.